# H-1 (Work visa) data by year by state

Tags: data-request, usa, government, state, migration

I am doing a research paper about how immigration impacts GDP, and I would like to know where can I find data about H-1 (Work visa):
Who is coming to the US because of work, and which state does he/she enter?

For example: Paul is from the UK, and he got a H-1B visa, and he is working for a company in CA, starting in 2008.

I would like to have the data from 1994 to 2013, or 1993-2013.

t doesn't matter which country they are from, and what industries. I just want to know each State's number of H1 visa by year by state.

I tried the Department of states, USCIS, Department of Labor, and more, and still can not find the data I was looking for in the past 10 years.

Comment: This might be a candidate for a FOIA request - http://www.foia.gov/how-to.html

Answer (score 1):

The Department of Homeland Security has a table with breakdown by State, but not by Visa type. Probably you can find similar data sets for previous years.

- [Webpage](http://www.dhs.gov/yearbook-immigration-statistics-2013-lawful-permanent-residents)
- [Excel file](http://www.dhs.gov/sites/default/files/publications/immigration-statistics/yearbook/2013/LPR/immsuptable1d.xls)

> Persons Obtaining Lawful Permanent Resident Status by State or Territory of Residence and Region and Country of Birth: Fiscal Year 2013
>   (XLS, 175 KB)

Also from DHS is a breakdown by State over year, but without country of origin - [Excel, 2008 data](http://www.dhs.gov/xlibrary/assets/statistics/yearbook/2008/table04.xls).

---

In general, you can search the **[data.gov](http://www.data.gov/)** portal for "immigration" and more search terms.

```
http://catalog.data.gov/dataset?q=immigration
```

Doing so returns my 359 data sets aggregated from multiple government sources. Scan through those results and perhaps you'll find exactly what you are looking for.